# Accessing a variable from Chrome's console

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

I've created a function inside a class that I'll use later on to run some code when called via a HTTP Post request. To be able to call the function from the outside of the class, I thought creating a variable outside the class and assigning it as soon as the class is instantiated would suffice. Helas, it did not.

Is there a way to access a variable declared outside of a Typescript class from Google Chrome's console?

```
export var setRotationCallback;

export class SceneComponent implements OnInit {

 /* Some code around here */

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    setRotationCallback = setRotation;

    /* Some more here */

    function setRotation(jsonList: string)
    {
      console.log("Received callback");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could stick the function on the global window object of the browser:
window.setRotationCallback = setRotation;

then in the browser console you could call it with window.setRotationCallback();

Comment: To be fair, I was expecting something more complex than that, but this did work perfectly! Thank you!